# app.js connection to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-connection

in my server, I put a nodejs file called app.js and will run from the console on a ubuntu server, but I get this error which I have put the errors below.

I've tried node-gyp rebuild and it will still not work but get error during update:

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! Stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1 
gyp ERR! stack to ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:343:16) 
gyp ERR! stack to ChildProcess.emit (events.js: 98: 17) 
gyp ERR! stack to Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js: 810: 12) 
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-37-virtual 
gyp ERR! command "node" "/ usr / bin / node-gyp" "rebuild" 
gyp ERR! CWD / root 
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.31 
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2 
gyp ERR! not ok

root@server1:~# node app.js
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

/root/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:409
          throw err
                ^
Error: failed to connect to [198.187.30.124:27017]
    at null. (/root/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/serve                                                                                        r.js:546:74)
    at emit (events.js:106:17)
    at null. (/root/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/conne                                                                                        ction_pool.js:150:15)
    at emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket. (/root/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/con                                                                                        nection.js:533:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:440:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)

Comment: are you able to use `mongo client` directly in `terminal/dos`??

Comment: i think your `mongod` server is not running, start it up, by typing `sudo mongod` in your teminal.

Comment: when i started the db i got thi error: ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo

Comment: create this directory, run `mkdir /data` then `mkdir /data/db`, then run your `mongod`

Comment: when i running mongo it's says, is it connect to mongodb now?: root@server1:~# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.1
connecting to: test

Comment: yes, and you should know a little about the platform/technology before starting to implement something in it